# Hive and protobuf parquet files, automatically infer all fields

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet

I use Hive to read parquet files. These files are generated with a protobuf schema.

Today here is the query to create the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${table_name_parquet} (
  data STRUCT<
    userId: BIGINT,
    operationId: STRING,
    ...
  >,
  product STRUCT<
    producturl: STRING
    ...
  >
)
PARTITIONED BY (user INT)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

Each of the fields is already declared in .proto files. My question is, is there a way to directly provide the protobuf file in order to automatically infer all fields ? Or maybe use the schema of the Parquet file ?

Edit: Im my use case, the LOCATION of the files are given after the table creation because the location change for each partition.

Thanks

Comment: Parquet tables already have a schema as part of them. The only Hive table schema information you should be required to provide is partitions /buckets

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well that is my question, how to use the schema of the parquet files.

Comment: Remove the data and product structs from the table definition. For external tables, you should specify a location of the directory where the _parquet files_ are stored. Hive doesn't read Protobuf, last I checked

Comment: @OneCricketeer The location is given after the CREATE call with an ALTER because it differs for each partition

Comment: Okay. That doesn't change the fact that you shouldn't need to define the `data` and `product` fields, though

Comment: How should have defined it ?

Comment: Like I said, have you tried removing all the fields and keeping the partitions? `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE x PARTITIONED BY y STORED AS PARQUET`